# App Engine switch to High Replication

Tags: google-app-engine

Am I right in thinking you CANNOT change a Goole AppEngine Application into High Replication.

What you do is migrate to a new app that is High Replication. Delete the App re create as High Replication and migrate back.

Is there a quicker way?

Comment: You can't create a new app with the same appid as a deleted app. The migration process will set up an alias from the old appid to the new one for you, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Migrating Applications](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/migration) (official guide from Google)

but basically:

1. You cannot change.
2. Clone the application.
3. Migrate the Data.
4. Disable old app.